# ICommand can not be hitted from CollectionView button

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, maui

In my application utilizing Mvvm.Toolkit, I've encountered an issue where a button placed within a CollectionView fails to invoke the associated ICommand method in the ViewModel upon clicking. Intriguingly, a similar implementation worked seamlessly in another ViewModel. Despite confirming that all other aspects of the application are functioning correctly, the behavior within the CollectionView has presented a unique challenge.

It's worth noting that I've employed the Mvvm.Toolkit's ICommand mechanism to handle user interactions in various parts of the application successfully. However, within the specific context of a CollectionView, the expected behavior is not being observed.

While the ViewModel structure and ICommand implementation have been proven effective in a different scenario, the CollectionView seems to introduce a nuance that impacts the execution of the ICommand method. I've scrutinized the code for potential discrepancies but haven't identified any apparent issues.

View Model Class

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShoppingCart.Models
{

    public partial class ProductViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products {get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string productId;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string productName;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string description;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string imageUrl;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int quantity;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int price;

       
        public ProductViewModel()
        {
            GetAllProducts();
        }
        [ICommand]
        public void EditProduct()
        {
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello", "sdfs", "Ok");
        }
        public void GetAllProducts()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "https://834xqncj-7275.inc1.devtunnels.ms/api/Product/Index";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            HttpResponseMessage response =  client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(content);
                Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(products);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ShoppingCart.Models"
             x:DataType="vm:ProductViewModel"
             x:Class="ShoppingCart.Pages.AdminPage"
             Title="AdminPage">
  
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="AddBtn"  Text="AddProduct"  Clicked="AddBtn_Clicked"/>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Opacity="0.7" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="End">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Title" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='Price: {0:C}'}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Subtitle" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditProductCommand}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        
                       
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

How to hit EditProduct method through ICommand

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can read the official document about the [Relative Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0). And you can [bind to an ancestor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#bind-to-an-ancestor). Such as:

```
<Button Text="Edit"
 Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ProductViewModel}}, Path=EditProductCommand}"
" />
```